# Cannot extract data from a hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes:

```
array_hash = [{product: 'A', qty: 1}, {product: 'B', qty: 2}]
```

I want to get the value of the first key `"product"`.

I get the expected hash with this code:

```
get_first_hash = array_hash[0]
# => {product: 'A', qty: 1}
```

However, this code returns `nil`:

```
get_value = get_first_hash['product']
# => nil
```

I hope someones can tell me about this.

Comment: This is because `:product == 'product' #=> false`

Comment: Your hash does not have a key `"product"` (although you have key `:product`). Don't use (hash) literals without knowing what it means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this suffices!

`array_hash.first[:product]`

If you want the second one you just do

```
array_hash.second[:product]
```

Also, .first is just a helper for doing array_hash[0], but the issue behind you getting nil is that you need to represent it with a :symbol in Ruby

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're accustom to using Hash in Ruby on Rails, which subclasses the [`Hash`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Hash.html) class that comes with Ruby as [`HashWithIndifferentAccess`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html), and you usually never forced to look at this as a developer (in Rails). It should also be noted, that Rails [directly modifies](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/Hash.html) Ruby's base [`Hash`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Hash.html) class, so you actually have a lot more available to you in Rails (or, specifically when [ActiveSupport](https://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport) is loaded).

Ruby (pure), however doesn't mess around when it comes to keys in the hash. This allows for some powerful applications—remember, everything in Ruby is an Object.

So, `'string'` and `:symbol` are both objects, and different objects at that. You can even use a `Class` as a key in your hash.

```
{
  Object => :object_symbol,
  Class => :class_symbol
}
```

So when you're trying to access values behind a key in your hash, make sure you use the exact key itself.

In your example above, you're using the symbol `product` as your key. Ruby uses `:` to denote that.

```
{
  product: 'A',
  qty: 1
}
```

This is the equivalent of saying

```
{
  :product => 'A',
  :qty => 1
}
```

So what you want to call is `get_value = get_first_hash[:product]`

Comment: Thank you so much for your detail answer. It really works for me. Because I am a newbie in Ruby and I am trying to learn by myself so there is something I can not handle it. Thank you

Comment: @NguyenKhoiNguyen here at Stack Overflow, we try to accept answers that have the most explanation that also addresses the question. Please consider changing your accepted answer.